# Pass a variable in awk command

Tags: bash, environment-variables, awk

```
  spke="myvaribale"
  var="cidr"
  val=$azure_spoke2_vnet_cidr
  clp="azure_vnets"
```

I am placing these variable in this command : I dont want to write this  `myvaribale`  in `awk` rather I want to use  `$spke` variable there when I use directly in command its not working.

```
  awk -v spke="$spke" -v var="$var" -v val="$val" -v clp="$clp" '/variable/ { cloudp=gensub(/(^variable[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\2",$0) } /myvaribale[[:space:]]=/ { spoke=$1 } spoke==spke && $1==var && cloudp ~ clp { $0=gensub(/(^.*=[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1"val"\\3",$0) }1'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that `/regexp/` is shorthand for `$0 ~ /regexp/`.

In the `$0 ~ /regexp/` form, you can replace `/regexp/` (in which the thing between slashes is a *string constant*) by a [computed regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) using string concatenation:

```
$0 ~ spke "[[:space:]]="
```

where `spke` is the awk variable that you initialized on the command with `-v spke="myvariable"`